# handling 'open questions' in CS.stackexchange

Tags: discussion

A lot of questions here have been answered, but not many of them have been accepted by the asker, i realized this is more common among the new users.

Has anybody thought about addressing this problem?

Having so many questions open makes it difficult to identify the ones actually need to be closed. (also i think it reflects poorly on the site)

Comment: Your basic concern is valid. Note, however, that questions do not count as "open" in the prominent statistics if the have answers which received (several?) upvotes. Acceptance is not necessary. As far as I know, we have no way of forcing users to accept an answer (and sometimes not accepting any of the existing answers is legitimate). By the way, this is [not a new problem](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/533/percentage-of-answered-questions). Strategies exist, but require work. You can imagine the rest.

Comment: acceptance is a nice mechanism but requires more regular users, more of a community. as for many questions, maybe you havent noticed that anything that is not very current (within a few days) gets very little activity, its more historical/search engine bait. new answers on old questions are rare. also suggest more users in chat could increase community cohesion.

Comment: @Raphael, I think an answer with positive total vote is enough I think.